# How to process a form in WordPress and create an XML file out of its data?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a form, and out of the data that is submitted from this form I want to create an XML file and save this file to a specific path.

I don't know how to pass the data to a PHP file in WordPress. Usually I would just pass the path of the PHP file in the action attribute and handle the data.

But how do I do this in WordPress?
I created the form without a plugin.

I am new to WordPress and still trying to figure things out.

This is the form:

```
<form action="???" method="post">
        
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="XMLBanf">
        
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" required="">

        <label for="departement">Abteilung</label>
        <select name="Abteilung">
            <option value="keine_angabe">Keine Angabe</option>
            <option value="vertrieb">Vertrieb</option>
            <option value="it">IT</option>
            <option value="service">Service</option>
            <option value="lager">Lager</option>
        </select>

        <label for="order">Was soll bestellt werden: </label>
        <textarea name="order" cols="30" rows="10" required=""></textarea>

        <label for="reason_order">Grund der Bestellung</label>
        <input type="text" name="reason_order" required="">

        <label for="price">Angebotspreis</label>
        <input type="number" name="price" required="">

        <label for="offer_file"></label>
        <input type="file">

        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Abschicken">
    </form>
```

then I would try to handle the data like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><order></order>");

    $xml->addChild('name',$_POST['name']);
    $xml->addChild('departement',$_POST['departement']);
    $xml->addChild('order',$_POST['order']);
    $xml->addChild('reason_order',$_POST['reason_order']);
    $xml->addChild('price',$_POST['price']);

    $fileName = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true))."banf.xml";
    $asXML= $xml->asXML();
    $file = fopen($fileName, "w+");
    fwrite($file, $asXML);
    fclose($file);
    print_r(error_get_last());

    if(file_exists("./".$fileName)){
        $myXML = file_get_contents("./".$fileName);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($myXML);
        $xmlpretty = $xml->asXML();

        // pretty print the XML in browser
        header('content-type: text/xml');
        echo $xmlpretty;
    }
```

How do I access this file now?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the `init` action (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) in your functions.php file or custom plugin.

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Process submission here.
} );
```

You can set the URL for the action of the form to the `home_url()` for example: `action="<?php esc_url( home_url() ); ?>"`. Any WordPress generated page will trigger your `init` action, running your code.

A couple of things to note:

1. "submit" is too vague and can potentially conflict with other submits, so make sure you add a hidden input with a unique and clear name for your action.
2. Make sure you use nonces for forms to combat CSRFs. While you might think that you don't have a vulnerability now, it's important to get used to adding nonces to all forms as a security best-practice: https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/nonces/#adding-a-nonce-to-a-form
3. Don't forget to `exit;` and short-circuit your output to prevent WordPress from loading the homepage further.

Comment: Thanks for answering and welcome me. Didn’t have the time to try it. But i will. Happy Christmas and a nice new eve if you celebrate.